# In an R interactive session, how can I access the value of the most recent expression?

Tags: r, interactive, interpreter

When I'm in an interactive session with R and I type a command (e.g., log(25)), the interpreter displays the result

```
> log(25)
[1] 3.218876
>
```

is that result available as the value of some special variable that I can use on the next line?

Comment: This is programming, and so technically off topic here. But answer is easy:  give it a name. Try the following R code `a = log(25);  exp(a)`.

Comment: Try `.Last.value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Last.value` does that trick:

```
> .Last.value
$help_type
NULL

> 5
[1] 5
> .Last.value
[1] 5
> iris; .Last.value
```

However I do not really know, whether one should ever use that. Just give things an explicit name. It takes less key strokes to write

```
> (a <- 5)
[1] 5
> a
[1] 5
```

and then everybody can easily see what happens and if you come back later to your script and enter an additional line, that will do not harm.

From the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

> Simple is better than complex.

> Readability counts.

> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

> If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks: Not a very easy-to-type name, unfortunately.

Comment: If you use a console or editor with auto completion, that is no big deal. If not, concern yourself with better tools!

Comment: I'm working interactively, not coding. If I had anticipated that I wanted to access the value of the expression, I would have assigned it to a variable. But I didn't anticipate it, and that is why I need Last.value. Auto completion works nicely. Other languages (e.g., Matlab, Mathematica, and Common Lisp have much shorter ways of accessing the last value.